# php if and statement causing problems

Tags: php, variables

Im trying to test a validation using an if statement.

```
if (($red == "1") && ($blue = "1") ) { $green = "hello"; }
```

Before this statement runs `$blue = 0`.

After i run this... `$blue` changes to `1`.

Any ideas why?

Comment: sorry i meant to say BEFORE i run, $blue = 0

Comment: $blue++; ? is that what u want? correct = to == in second brackets

Comment: brian, edit your post to correct it. There's an "edit" link right below the tags.

Comment: Just read the code you posted once more, you should be able to find the mistake...

Comment: I seriously wonder though..., you managed to do it right for `$red == "1"` but not for `$blue`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `=` in place of `==`:

```
if (($red == "1") && ($blue = "1") ) { $green = "hello"; }
                           ^^^
```

As a result (assuming the left side of `&&` returns true) `$blue` ***gets assigned*** `"1"`.

It's one of the most common programming mistakes!! As a way to prevent it from happening programmers put the constant on the left hand side of the the `==` as:

```
1 == $blue
```

so that if by mistake you end up writing `=` in place of `==` :

```
1 = $blue
```

you get a syntax error as you cannot assign to a constant.

Comment: after so many hours i just couldn't see it! sometimes it takes someone else to see the simple. thanks

Comment: @brianwilsonL: I've updated the answer with a tip to avoid such bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Try this if (($red == "1") && ($blue == "1") ) { $green = "hello"; }

//your code is ($blue ="1") '=' is an assignment operator in php comparison is '=='

Answer (score 1):

you are assigning `$blue = 1` instead of comparing that's why $blue is 1

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use `=`. Use `$blue == "1"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your equal to sing is incorrect in next condistions
    if (($red == "1") && ($blue == "1") ) { $green = "hello"; }

Answer (score 0):

Yeah use `==` instead of `=`

I would go further and say that maybe you should put literals on the left hand when comparing to avoid such situations.

Like `if(1 == $blue)` instead of `if($blue == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

use **==** or **===** instead of **=**.

the '=' is **assignment** operator, the **conditional** operators are **==** or **===**

```
if (($red == "1") && ($blue == "1") ) 
 { 
     $green = "hello"; 
 }
```